# Fonts in Inkscape Vector showing odd space when they overlap

Tags: inkscape, type

I downloaded a bunch of fonts and I've been having problems mostly with the script/cursive ones.

[image]

You can see here how the font is glitching and it happens with every other font that's not far apart, aka the script or handwritten ones that are connected.

And I've noticed that in the other typefaces the light/thin variations simply don't work. I can go down to regular and up to bold is okay, but it won't let me go on thin and light and I haven't found a solution anywhere else so far.

Comment: Hi.  I've answered your first question as that is easilly fixed. However, as for the fonts you say don't work, what do you mean by that? Can you select them in the font dropdown? Are they not displaying properly? Have you installed the other variants? Which fonts are they?  Do they work in other software? There is a possibility that a font file could be corrupt, but it's really hard to tell what is wrong without knowing which specific font you are talking about.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that did it. About the second problem, the bigger one, it happens with example Josefin Sans i downloaded I think from 1001fonts, and a bunch of other ones that have weights below Light or regular. Example I have regular weight and then I want light or extra light and but it stays the same. It also says weight=255 on some of those thin/light weights.

On the little window displaying what the font should look like before apply it shows it going thinner/bolder but when I click apply it doesn't change. Happens with Montserrat too.

Comment: Jospefin Sans and Montserrat seem to work just fine, at least if you download them from Google Fonts. I just tested them. Maybe unistall them, and get your copies direct from googlefonts, and reinstall them. These are variable fonts, so not sure if that is giving you some issues, however I've found none. They seems to work as expected.  Also, are you using the most recent Inskcape 1.3.2?  Variable fonts are kind of new, so not sure if they work in older versions of Inkscape. I think it was only fixed recently.

Comment: Note there are also static versions of those fonts too, so if you want to use in an older version of Inkscape, it would be possible to install those variants too. They're in the zip folder when you download from googlefonts, inside the folder named "Static".

Comment: I use version 1.3.2, yeah.Thanks, I will try directly from Google Fonts and see if that makes a difference for me.

Comment: I downloaded Nunito, Josefin Sans and Montserrat from Google Fonts. Most of the weights work now, that's fine, although I have a problem where Italics won't show on some Montserrat weights and not at all in Nunito. In Josefin Sans only one Italic works on Thin Italic.

Comment: Okay I just noticed that Italics work when I select the fonts from the toolbar and not the Text and Font dialog? That's odd.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this. It looks like a possible bug. I checked with other variable fonts, and it doesn't seem to want to apply the italic, or adjust the sliders once italic has been chosen, and reverts to a non-italic variant instead when hitting apply.. You might want to [report this](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/) to the developers.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text object, then open up the Fill and Stroke panel <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, click the Fill tab, then at the top right corner choose the option for solid fill shown highlighted in red below.

[image]

As for your second question, the main variable font variants can be selected from the font dropdown, but in the Text and Font dialog, selecting italic or adjusting the weight doesn't seem to work, and it just reverts to a non-italic variant. This looks like a potential bug and should probably be [reported to the developers](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/).  Not much we can do about bugs here.

In the meantime, there are a couple of possible workarounds, but these are less than ideal.  Choose a non-italic variant, adjust its weight, and then switch to Italic in the font drop down. This is a bit glitchy for me, sometimes it works and sometimes not.  If that doesn't work, then the brute force method is to open up the XML editor, double click on the style, and add or adjust the font weight manually.

An example

[image]click to see larger